# Value of type 'Integer' cannot be converted to 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader'. vb.net

Tags: vb.net, type-conversion

i'm trying to read the last invoice number and display it in a textbox.....

Assume that, Table name is "MyTable" , Column name is "InvoiceNumber" and it is AutoNumber, So it is Integers!

Here's my code:

```
        Dim query As String = "SELECT MAX(InvoiceNumber) FROM MyTable"
        Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
        Dim reading As OleDb.OleDbDataReader

        cmd.CommandText = query
        cmd.Connection = conn

        reading = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar())

        If reading.Read Then
            TextBox1.Text = reading.Item("InvoiceNumber").ToString
        End If
```

Erorr is on "reading = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar())" because my Value is of type 'Integer' cannot be converted to 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader'.

Any help ... ?

Answer (score 1):

The variable `reading` is a `OleDbDataReader` which can't be used to assign an integer, that's the reason for the error. But you don't need a `DataReader` anyway if you use `ExecuteScalar`:

```
Dim maxNumber As Int32 = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
TextBox1.Text = maxNumber.ToString
```

Comment: Suggesting a check for DBNull on MAX

Comment: @Steve: maybe it would be exceptional at this point to find no number because he is in an insert method.

Comment: Yes, maybe, hope that he never adds a where to the sql.